# Laravel: Multiple model for one table

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, relationships

My Goals: maintain all users (agents, admins, students, teachers or can be more role) in on table but each individual model/role able to reference to another id on the same table base on role they have `$admins = Agent::with('agent')->get();`

NOTE: I already have table `roles` and `user_roles` which working just fine

```
users
===========
id
username
password
fullname

agent_student (one agent has many students but one student belongsTo one agent)
===========
id 
agent_id
student_id

admin_agent (one admin has many agents but one agent belongsTo one admin)
===========
id
admin_id
agent_id
```

app/Agent.php:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Agent extends User
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function student()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Student', 'id');
    }

    function agent_student()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AgentStudent', 'id');
    }
}
```

app/Student.php:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends User
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function agent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Agent', 'id');
    }

    public function agent_student()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\AgentStudent', 'student_id');
    }
}
```

app/AgentStudent.php:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserStudent extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_student';

    function student()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Student', 'id');
    }

    function agent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Agent', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see you your problem. And your question is badly formatted

Comment: Example
agent (1, 2)
student id (3, 4, 5, 6)
agent_student (1=>3, 1=>4, 2=>5, 2=>6)
(user  id 3 and 4 belong to user id 1..... user id 5 and 6 belong to user id 2)

if I call from controller

Student::find(3)->with('agent')->get();

I want it to return user id 1 not user id 3

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make it a self reference?

```
class Agent extends Eloquent {

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Agent', 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Agent', 'parent_id');
}
}
```